# How to read and write on cassandraDB node that is located on a different machine in the datacenter?

Tags: cassandra

I am a Cassandra newbie, I read that **Cassandra distributes the data across the network** (cluster, datacenter, etc), so I'd like to understand clearly something:

let's say I got 3 physical computers (host1,host2, and host3) with ubuntu16.04 and Cassandra installed on each one.

1. These computers are on my LAN, they can ping well one another
2. Now I create a keyspace **on my host1**

   `create KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'MyLAN': 3}`;
3. can I interact with created `mykeyspace` on the other **hosts? (host2 and host3)** using cqlsh client?
4. When I add another host4 to LAN can I still view `mykeyspace` after altering `mykeyspace` with replica 4?

any clear explanation or idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3. Yes, you can. There's nothing special about each individual C* node -- you can connect to any node.
4. Yes, you can. But you don't generally change the keyspace replication when you add nodes. Our general recommendation is 3 replicas per data center.

If you're interested, I've explained and included diagrams to illustrate it in great detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/5486/. Cheers!

Comment: Great explanation. Thx a bunch !!